# sql ibm db2 group by age range

Tags: sql, group-by, db2

I have a table `INFO` with an age parameter `AGE_YEARS`.
I need an output like this:

```
AGE_RANGE    COUNT
18-29        400 
30-49        500
50-69        ???
70-99        ???
```

How would a select statement look like for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
select (case when age_years >= 18 and age < 30 then '18-29'
             when age_years < 50 then '30-49'
             when age_years < 70 then '50-69'
             when age_years < 100 then '70-100'
        end) as age_range, count(*)
from REDACTED
group by (case when age_years >= 18 and age < 30 then '18-29'
               when age_years < 50 then '30-49'
               when age_years < 70 then '50-69'
               when age_years < 100 then '70-100'
          end)
order by min(age_years);
```